Is this a safe way of re-assigning a cleared vector of unique_ptrs from another one
I have a case on my code where I have to clear a vector of unique_ptrs, but then I have to re-assign it with other values from another vector of unique_ptrs. I'm looking for a safe way of doing it. Note: I'm only able to use until c++14.
This is what I'm thinking of doing. For simplicity this is just a simple class, but the real class I'm working on it's an abstract class. I was wondering if the way I'm doing it here it's safe and doesn't invoke UB. I'm mainly concerned about the clear() being  enough to delete the unique_ptrs stored in goodStudents. I've seen in other places where after a clear of a vector of unique_ptr there is shrink_to_fit() called as well. Then is std::move() to reassign the vector of goodStudents. Is it better to use another function like insert() here instead ?
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Students
{
public:
    Students(int age, std::string name) :
    age_(age), name_(name)
    {
        
    }
    
    int age_;
    std::string name_;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Students>> goodStudents;
    goodStudents.push_back(std::make_unique<Students>(5, "Troy"));
    goodStudents.push_back(std::make_unique<Students>(4, "George"));
    goodStudents.clear();
    
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Students>> badStudents;
    badStudents.push_back(std::make_unique<Students>(6, "Cole"));
    badStudents.push_back(std::make_unique<Students>(4, "Maynard"));
    
    if(goodStudents.empty())
    {
        goodStudents = std::move(badStudents);    
    }
    
    for(const auto& student: goodStudents)
    {
        std::cout << "student.name " << student->name_ << "\n";
    }
}


This code seems to achieve the goal you describe.  What exactly is your question?

@DrewDormann I was just wondering if this was a safe way of doing. I'm not invoking any UB, etc...

Side note : Each instance of class Students holds the data for only one student. Therefore, it should probably be named Student (singular) rather than Students (plural).

std::unique_ptr is not necessary in the shown code.

The behavior of this code is well-defined.  If that answers your question.

@DrewDormann it does.

Which part are you concerned about? I see two distinct steps that could/should be considered separately. 1) You have a filled vector and you need to clear it (done by goodStudents.clear();). 2) You have an empty vector and you need to fill it from another vector (done by the if). There's no interaction between these steps (assuming your version of the standard library is not seriously bugged). It seems like you could skip the initial fill-and-clear of goodStudents. Why do you think it's significant?

@JaMiT I was concerned about the clear() being to enough to delete the unique_ptrs stored in goodStudents I've seen other places where after a clear of a vector of unique_ptr there is shrink_to_fit() called as well. Then is std::move() to reassign the vector good, or is it better to use another function like insert() ?

std::clear will call all the destructors of the contained objects (but the memory is still allocated by the vector). The srhink_to_fit is there to release memory. In other words the lifetime of the allocated memory is distinct from the lifetime of the contained objects.

Note that shrink_to_fit is non-binding and often implemented for maximum speed, ultimately doing nothing.

"I'm mainly concerned about the clear() being enough to [...]" -- If this is your main concern, you should drop the part where you assign new values to the vector. Questions should be limited to one question. Although, I would present this differently. Rather than asking if your code has undefined behavior, you could ask what benefit there is when other people call shrink_to_fit() after clear().
